Pandas dataframe round doesn't work when applying style
I have this code that prints a dataframe in a table:
def printSegments(segments_ref, segments_hyp, timestamps_ref, timestamps_hyp):
    def highlight_unequal_rows(row):
        if len(row['reference'].split()) != len(row['hypothesis'].split()):
            return ['background-color: red'] * len(row)
        return [''] * len(row)
    
    start_diff = [th["start"] - tr["start"] for th, tr in zip(timestamps_hyp, timestamps_ref)]
    dur_diff = [th["dur"] - tr["dur"] for th, tr in zip(timestamps_hyp, timestamps_ref)]
    df = pd.DataFrame(dict(reference=segments_ref, hypothesis=segments_hyp, start_hyp_minus_ref=start_diff, dur_hyp_minus_ref=dur_diff))
    pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', None)

    df = df.style.apply(highlight_unequal_rows, axis=1)
    df = df.set_table_styles(
        [
            {'selector': 'td', 'props': [('direction', 'ltr'), ('text-align', 'left')]},
            {'selector': 'th', 'props': [('direction', 'ltr'), ('text-align', 'left')]}
        ],
        overwrite=False
    )
    return df

I'm trying to round values in the last two columns (start_hyp_minus_ref, dur_hyp_minus_ref) to two digits after the decimel point.
I tried:
f = {'start_hyp_minus_ref':'{:.2f}'}
df.style.format(f).bar(subset='start_hyp_minus_ref')

And:
df['start_hyp_minus_ref'] = df['start_hyp_minus_ref'].round(2)
df['dur_hyp_minus_ref'] = df['dur_hyp_minus_ref'].round(2)

But that doesn't work. If I remove the styling (last block in the code) it works.
You can try and run the code:
printSegments(["I went to the school"], ["I want to the school"], [{"start": 0.69, "dur": 1.5}], [{"start": 0.79, "dur": 1.3}])


df = df.style... - Oof, don't do that. A styler is not a dataframe. IDK if that's related to the problem though. Please make a [mre] so that it's easier to follow. To start, I'd just provide df (the actual dataframe) instead of all the code that builds it.

Where did you put df.style.format(f)...? That doesn't have any effect on its own...

How can I highlight certain rows without using df.style..., I would be happy for other suggestions

I'm saying the name df is confusing for a Styler object. Use a different name.

BTW, pd.set_option() has a global effect, so this function isn't pure. Instead you could maybe set a context and return a rendered table or something like that. with pd.option_context('display.max_colwidth', None): return <df Styler>.to_html()

@wjandrea I did the changes but still can't figure out how the styling is preventing me from rounding the values :(

OK, please make a [mre] and show how you're using df.style.format(f)...

I added these loc to solve the problem:
df["start_hyp_minus_ref"] = [str(round(x, 2)) for x in df["start_hyp_minus_ref"]]
df["dur_hyp_minus_ref"] = [str(round(x, 2)) for x in df["dur_hyp_minus_ref"]]


Why do it manually when you can use .format(f)? You're on the right track in the question, but IDK where you're stuck since you haven't showed it.

This changes the dtype, so if you wanted to add more styling later, this could get in the way.
